# How do I close an Excel spreadsheet in VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, file, ms-access

I have the following routine below that is meant to open an Excel spreadsheet and then go row by row to import the results into a table that is passed in. It works fine but the problem is if I try to open that same spreadsheet a second time I get a message that the file is in use and I have to Ctrl-Alt-Del to shut down Excel before I can use it again. I thought that the Set mySheet=Nothing and Set xlApp=Nothing would release the file but apparently not. What more can I do to make sure that Access lets go of the Excel file?  Thanks in advance!

```
Public Sub MakeTempTable(strFilePath As String, tablename As String)
    Dim mySheet As Object
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim sql As String
    sql = "DELETE * FROM " & tablename
    DoCmd.RunSQL sql
    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(tablename)
    
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set mySheet = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath).Sheets(1)
    xlApp.Visible = False
    Set mySheet = xlApp.Sheets("Input")
    
    Dim dRows As Double
    dRows = 1
    Dim dRow As Double, dCol As Double
    dRow = 2
    On Error GoTo ERR
    Do
        dCol = 1
        rs.AddNew
        If mySheet.cells(dRow, 3) = "" Then Exit Do
        Do
            If mySheet.cells(dRow, dCol).Value <> "_END_" Then
                rs.Fields(dCol).Value = Nz(mySheet.cells(dRow, dCol).Value, "")
            dCol = dCol + 1
            Else
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
        rs.Update
        dRow = dRow + 1
    Loop

EXITSUB:
    Set mySheet = Nothing
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Sub
ERR:
    If ERR.Number = 3265 Then MsgBox "The species selected are incompatible. Canceling import.", vbCritical, "IMPORT ERROR"
    GoTo EXITSUB
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
xlApp.Quit
```

When you set xlApp to nothing you are only clearing the object within the procedure, you aren't doing anything to the actual Excel instance.  All that setting XXX = nothing allows you to do is then reuse that object.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to legally close the workbooks that are open as in

```
  xlApp.Workbooks.Close
  
EXITSUB:
```

This will close the instances that are open.

Prior to this, kill all the instances or reboot your machine to clear all the instances that are open.